# _SESSION Lost in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, session

I have this:

captcha.php

```
<?php
session_start();
$code=rand(1000,9999);
$_SESSION["code"]=$code;
$im = imagecreatetruecolor(50, 24);
$bg = imagecolorallocate($im, 22, 86, 165);
$fg = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
imagefill($im, 0, 0, $bg);
imagestring($im, 5, 5, 5,  $code, $fg);
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
header('Content-type: image/png');
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

then i call this in other php file:

```
<img src="captcha.php"/>
```

but the session is not saved...

thansk for your help guys!

Comment: Does the other script also invoke `session_start()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To start a session using PHP, `session_start()` needs to be the first thing before any HTML is output:

```
<?php
session_start();
```

from PHP.net:

> [Note:](https://www.php.net/session_start) To use cookie-based sessions, session_start() must be called
> before outputing anything to the browser.

Since you are including it as an image, this `session_start()` will not appear early enough in your output.  You need to make sure it's the first thing; I'm not sure how wordpress handles that on its own, perhaps a question for the wordpress forum.  [Here is a post](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/using-session-in-wordpress) I found about the subject.